# Python: count the matrix values according to the threshold

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

Help me, please)
I have a numpy array 160x160
What i need is to count an amount of indexes whose value is between value a and b. 
What i tried:
A - my matrix

```
for i in A:
   for j in A[i]:
      if A[i,j] < 0.1 and A[i,j]> 0:
          m=collections.Counter(don't know what to write here)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why sort, when you say you want to count between certain values? Can you clarify? And, doesn't this `((A>0) & (A<0.1)).sum()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example  extension for the comment

Let `arr` be random array

```
In [33]: arr = np.random.rand(160,160)
```

Get the number of elements which are `>0 & <0.1`

```
In [34]: ((arr>0) & (arr<0.1)).sum()
Out[34]: 2649
```